# Getstream Chat Error: AnimatedValue: Attempting to set value to undefined

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

I am working with Getstream chat SDk in react native,
My package.json file looks like:

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.4",
**"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.1",**
"react-native-device-info": "^5.6.2",
"react-native-document-picker": "^3.5.3",
"react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.2",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
"react-native-screens": "^2.9.0",
**"react-navigation": "4.1.0",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
"stream-chat-react-native": "^0.13.1"**
},

I am using the same react native code in the "native message example" provided in the link : https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-react-native

While running, The chat list screen is presenting , but on selecting a chat it shows an error as :

**Error: AnimatedValue: Attempting to set value to undefined**

Do anyone has the same issue, Could you please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> TLDR:

Mine working version for 1.3.2,
Please read readme.md and bug.md as walktrough.

https://github.com/ilovejs/ReactNative-GetStream-Bugfix

> Explaination:

What are the problems in 'official' demo ?

```
"react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.4"
index.js introduce patch uuid crpyto bug, that reported in readme.md
"react-native-reanimated": "1.13.1",
```